# which is better approach while getting data from server and display on list?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Hi can you please tell me which is a better approach while getting data from server and displaying on a list?

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class ConnectJson extends Thread {

 private String url;
 public String response;
 private String myinterface = ";deviceside=true";
 private JsonObserver observer;


  public void run() {
         HttpConnection conn = null;
         InputStream in = null;
         int code;

   try {
      conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(this.url + this.myinterface, Connector.READ);
         conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
         code = conn.getResponseCode();
         System.out.println("naveen-------------------------");
         if (code == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             in = conn.openInputStream();
             byte[] buffer = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in);
             this.response = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
             if (observer != null) {
                 observer.onResponseReceived(this.response);
             }



             if (in != null){
                 in.close();
             }
             if (conn != null){
                 conn.close();
             }
         }

     } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.inform(e.toString());
     }
}  

public String jsonResult(String url){
  this.url = url;
 this.start();
// this.run();
  return response;
 }

public void setObserver(JsonObserver o) {
    this.observer = o;
}
}
```

---

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Vector;

import xjson.me.JSONArray;
import xjson.me.JSONException;
import xjson.me.JSONObject;


import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements JsonObserver
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        

        ConnectJson connectJson = new ConnectJson();
        System.out.println("------------------");
        connectJson.setObserver(this);

        connectJson.jsonResult("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/59211ea4-ffd2-4ad9-9a4e-941d3148024a?inc=artist-credits+labels+discids+recordings&fmt=json");

        System.out.println("---------bbbbb---------");





    }


    public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
        System.out.println("000000000000000000000000000000000"+response);

        // TODO: create or update your ListField here!!!
    }
}
```

---

```
package mypackage;

public interface JsonObserver {
       public void onResponseReceived(String response);
    }
```

Comment: By the way, you should try not to *replace* your original question with a whole new set of code.  When you do that, other readers can't see the question you originally asked.  If you want to add updates, just **edit** the question and add the new code below the original code.  Also, please try to post only the code you need to show us.  Lots of extra space, auto-generated comments, and import statements just make the code harder to read.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, this will not work:

```java
public String jsonResult(String url){
   this.url = url;
   this.start();

   return response;
}
```

Calling `start()` will cause `run()` to be called on a background thread (that's good).  However, immediately after you start the background thread, you return the `response` member variable.  That won't work, because the `run()` method hasn't had time to actually assign the `response` variable.

What you need to do is assign the `response` variable at the end of the `run()` method, and then notify the UI on the main/UI thread, to let it update the user interface.  Something like this:

```java
     if (code == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
         in = conn.openInputStream();
         byte[] buffer = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in);
         this.response = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // this code is run on the main/UI thread
                if (observer != null) {
                    observer.onResponseReceived(this.response);
                }
            }
         });
```

where you add a new observer interface

```java
public interface JsonObserver {
   public void onResponseReceived(String response);
}
```

and then you can let your `MainScreen` implement that interface:

```java
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements JsonObserver {

    public MyScreen()
    {        
        connectJson.setObserver(this);
        // start the json request
        connectJson.jsonResult("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/59211ea4-ffd2-4ad9-9a4e-941d3148024a?inc=artist-credits+labels+d...");
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(String response) {
        System.out.println("000000000000000000000000000000000"+response);

        // TODO: create or update your ListField here!!!
    }
```

Of course, you'll need a new member and method in the `ConnectJson` class, too:

```java
private JsonObserver observer;

public void setObserver(JsonObserver o) {
    observer = o;
}
```

---

*Note: it also might be better, for thread safety, to change your `response` member variable to a simple local `final` variable.  I can't know all the ways that you plan on using it, but if it's just a way to hold onto the JSON response, you probably don't need a member variable.  Try this instead (inside of `run()`):*

```java
     final String response = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
     UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             observer.onResponseReceived(response);
```

Comment: Good answer can you make a simple example so that I can understand

Comment: please check my update ..is this a way you are saying..?

Comment: yes, your new code looks good.  update your list where i put a **TODO** comment.